# how to line up radio buttons and text

Tags: css

I have added

```
.form-radio{
display: block;
}
```

to make my radio buttons be one under the other , instead of next to each other.  but now the text associated with each button is coming out underneath as well.  I want the text for each radio to be next to the radio button.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type">
 <input id="edit-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type-1" name="submitted[contactus_question_type_label][contactus_question_type]" value="&quot;general" class="form-radio" type="radio">  

<label class="option" for="edit-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type-1">General, questions about student aid or about your own student aid situation, including your student loans or questions/comments about any website content." </label>

</div> 

<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type">
 <input id="edit-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type-2" name="submitted[contactus_question_type_label][contactus_question_type]" value="&quot;technical" class="form-radio" type="radio">  

<label class="option" for="edit-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type-2">Technical Question, questions or comments about our website (such as a broken link or something else not working properly)." </label>
    </div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is your HTML structure?

Comment: Are you using <label> elements for your <radio> elements? We need to see your HTML that defines the radio buttons.

Comment: @DianaCastillo try editing your question with the HTML instead.

Comment: You can hit "edit" underneath your question to improve / update it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 .form-type-radio {
     display: block;
 }
 .form-type-radio input,
 .form-type-radio label {
     display: inline;
 }
```

```css
    .form-type-radio {
      display: block;
    }
    .form-type-radio input,
    .form-type-radio label {
      display: inline;
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type">
  <input id="edit-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type-1" name="submitted[contactus_question_type_label][contactus_question_type]" value="&quot;general" class="form-radio" type="radio">
  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type-1">Gen‌eral, questions about student aid or about your own student aid situation, including your student loans or questions/comments about any website content."</label>

</div>

<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type">

  <input id="edit-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type-1" name="submitted[contactus_question_type_label][contactus_question_type]" value="&quot;general" class="form-radio" type="radio">
  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type-1">Other Stuff</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but that didnt work, the word are still underneath the radio button.

Comment: no, now with those new changes, the radio buttons are no longer below each other, everything is inline

Comment: Really? Something else must be going on. Does the code snippet I included work for you (radio buttons on separate lines)?

Comment: you were right there was other css which was colliding with it.  I fixed it thank you

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `.form-radio` like this:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0tjauw4y/)**

```css
.form-radio {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type">
    <input id="edit-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type-1" name="submitted[contactus_question_type_label][contactus_question_type]" value="&quot;general" class="form-radio" type="radio">
    <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type-1">General, questions about student aid or about your own student aid situation, including your student loans or questions/comments about any website content."</label>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type">
    <input id="edit-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type-2" name="submitted[contactus_question_type_label][contactus_question_type]" value="&quot;technical" class="form-radio" type="radio">
    <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-contactus-question-type-label-contactus-question-type-2">Technical Question, questions or comments about our website (such as a broken link or something else not working properly)."</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This ?

http://jsfiddle.net/ht6p0phv/1/

2 options:

1. wrap each radio buttons and their text in a block element like: `p`s
2. Use `<br />` at the end of the line

and there's more...

Comment: I cant wrap anything this is a drupal form which makes its own structure